# How can I feed images from a Raspberry Pi to a very old handheld projector?

Tags: raspberry-pi, display, displayport

I have this very old handheld projector:

[image: 3M Mobile Projection Engine]

And its connector cable looks like this (5mm wide, white), if I am not mistaken:

[image: white ribbon]

My questions are two-fold:

1. Can anyone guess what standard/format of input this projector accepts?
2. How can I feed images from a Raspberry Pi to this projector? Can it be as simple as finding a suitable DSI-to-whatever adapter and plug the connector cables in both ends?

The projector has stopped working for a while, and I just want to see if I can revive it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What inputs did the projector originally have?

Comment: It's a standalone projector which you insert an SD card storing all the images, and press a few button to get it playing.

Comment: looks like a 7 pin cable has been ripped off the board to the right of the red wire

Answer (score 3):

The TW881X series of chips take in analog video such as composite and RGB but also digital BT.601 type component video. It can outputs digital TTL RGB port for TFT, but it also has analog output.

Most likely the wide yellow flex cable is the pixel port. The white cable is not video at all, likely either power supplies to the projector module or something else.

A serious amount of reverse engineering needs to be done to know any pinout of any connector and it does not help if some part of the device is not working.